# Issue after informatica installation

Tags: installation, informatica

After Successful Installation of Informatica 9.6.1 server and client on win-8.1

i am facing the below error while configuring Domain  in IPC client Repository Manager tool:

Unable to save information for domain Domain_Hostname.

[PCSF_46026] Unable to find valid TrustStore certificate in PEM format 
[ERROR: Cannot connect to Integration Service [xx].][1]

Comment: Have you tried what the following link is suggesting? https://community.informatica.com/thread/48029

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @user5468563,the solution in mentioned link didn't work,but the idea and key words in the link has made me to find solution

At last i found solution for this question.
Actually i faced this issue because of enabing secure communication for the domain while installing INFA9.6.1 server.

solution is after successful installation log in Administrator console 
After successful Creation of Repository service and Integration service,
go to 
Integration service --> Edit Advanced Properties --> Trust Store -->
Add value in Trust Store,Enter the value for Trust Store using the following

syntax:
 /

for Example:
C:\Informatica\9.6.1\server\samples\WebServices\ssl/wsh.keystore
click OK and restart the service

Now,we can Configure Domain in Repository Manager and can Connect to Repository under respective domain